# Make error with erlang.mk

Tags: erlang, cowboy

While following the tutorial found here:
http://ninenines.eu/docs/en/cowboy/HEAD/guide/getting_started/
I did the following commands;

```
mkdir hello_erlang
cd hello_erlang
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ninenines/erlang.mk/master/erlang.mk
```

After following all these preceding steps in that tutorial, I typed;

```
make -f erlang.mk bootstrap bootstrap-rel
```

while in the ~/hello_erlang directory. This resulted in the following error.

```
make: erlang.mk: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target `erlang.mk'.  Stop.
```

I'm working in Ubuntu 14.04.
The question is- What packages or steps am I messing that resulted in this error and how might I get those and correct myself?

Comment: Can you show us the contents of hello_erlang?

Answer (score -1):

I found my error. I forgot I did not have git.
fix:

```
sudo apt-get install git
```

Comment: // , That seems completely unrelated to the actual error that this threw. How did you even find this out??

Comment: I think the mentioned error occurred due to a configuration issue or something related to Erlang, not Git.